# forEach deserialisation invoked and saved within the List definition

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a line in Flutter/Dart:

`detail: payloadJson['product'][0]['scoreDetailPersonal']?.forEach((item) => ProductDetailScoreDetail.fromMap(item)),`

`detail` node is of type `{List<ProductDetailScoreDetail> detail}` and the code above returns null after looping through and correctly converting the Map to the ProductDetailScoreDetail type.

Is it possible to make this `forEach` save each loop to the `detail` node as a List? I have tried variations on `.add` but can't come up with the right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `forEach` to [`map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) and then call `toList` to convert the returned `Iterable` to the `List` you need.

[`forEach`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.2/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html) simply iterates over each list element with the function provided and **has a return type of void**.

```dart
detail: payloadJson['product'][0]['scoreDetailPersonal']?.map((item) => ProductDetailScoreDetail.fromMap(item)).toList(),
```